# How to retrieve the owning publication of a component via anguilla framework?

Tags: 2013, cme

I have a 'Edit' button in RTF popup to edit the selected component. I have the selected component's context url in text box within popup. I need to open the parent component in a new window. Please help to get the parent publication of this component.

Thanks nuno, that worked. Is there a way to open the OOB editable popup(SS attached) from the anguilla framework to let the authors to select the option [image]to open the component.

Comment: Your follow-up question is actually quite different than your original. The answer to that is calling the Open command with a selection of that item URI. Perhaps you should ask it as a separate question (so someone else who wonders the same thing can find it easily)?

Comment: +1 - Do ask as a separate question given this one already has an accepted answer and it will be confusing to others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an item's owning publication by asking for it...

If I type the following in the Chrome Console I get the correct publication ID for the item.

```
var x = $models.getItem("tcm:1-23");
x.load(); // Insert smart async stuff here
x.getOwningPublication().getId();
```